# There's what appears to be an EOT (end of text) character in my data in a SQL table that I need to remove

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I remove an "end of text" character from a field in a SQL table?  I'm using SQL Server 2012.  In a nutshell, the client provides me a data file in CSV format.  This data file:

[image]

When I copy/paste this weird, backwards L character into Sublime Text Editor:
[image]

So, this is how I came up to the conclusion that this is an EOT character.  You're probably thinking at this point, this isn't in SQL.  You're right - but how we import data through our proprietary software is we "import" this file which will end up in a sort of "staging" dataset.  I then can apply a SQL query to strip this weird, non-alphanumeric character from this dataset.

So, how would I remove this character using a SQL query, and what is the appropriate way to do this?  Meaning, do I use the ASCII equivalent of this EOT character when doing a SQL `REPLACE`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Is sql server you would use REPLACE.

Comment: do I use the ASCII equivalent of this EOT character when doing a SQL REPLACE? @SeanLange

Comment: Again without knowing which DBMS I am guessing...in sql server you would just use REPLACE(YourColumn, CHAR(3), '')

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2012

Comment: OK then what I posted should work for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ASCII character set](http://www.ascii-code.com/) EOT is character 0x4. So:

`REPLACE(ColumnName,CHAR(4),'')`